Durable Functions + Azure Storage Account -> Multiple retry to Attempting to retrieve authentication token for resource 'https://storage.azure.com/'
Anyone else having a problem to let durable functions runtime get connection to Azure Storage Account? When you are running Local environment on your VS Code.
For me it is stuck on that and after many many attempts it finally works but this can happen for every request.
enter image description here
When function is finally invoked then the internal DefaultAzureCredential() is working smoothly. I have no idea which method Durable Functions use I tried to look from the Source code but could not find that logic.
But based on the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-configure-managed-identity)  it tries to get a token from the following locations, in the said order, for access to your Azure resources:

A local cache shared between Microsoft applications
The current user context in Visual Studio
The current user context in Visual Studio Code
The current user context in the Azure CLI

I am using PIM account, I have local account.... where I use Teams/Outlook/Devops/ etc...
installed software/other:
Azure Func Core Tools
Visual Studio Code
Python 3.11
PIM Cloud account
az account clear
az login
az set subscription
then there was some command to disable the WAM and I have tried that aswell.
Any help would be appreciated!
-YourCSVman
I have tried to log out, clear cache -> login again, set subscription to the one where storage account lays but no progress.
Also I have tried to func host start --verbose from just command line and not inside VS Code
Also I have Logged in with my PIM Cloud account in Azure.

Please provide your function code.

Is the issue resolved?

Follow below steps to configure Durable Functions with managed identity, refer the blog.

Create a function app and enable managed identity. I have enabled System Assigned Managed Identity.
Navigate to the interlinked storage account=>Access Control(IAM)=>Grant Storage Account Contributor,Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the function app's managed identity.


Add AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName: <Storage_Account_Name>  under FunctionApp=>Settings=>Environment Variables=>App Settings:

Code Snippet:
import logging
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(name: str) -> str:
   logging.info(f"Listing blobs for: {name}")
   credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
   blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=credential)
   container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("your-container-name")
   blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
   blob_names = [blob.name for blob in blob_list]
   return f"Blobs for {name}: {blob_names}"

Output:


Logs:


Hey, this works fine. Durable functions run smoothly in the function app. The local development does not.

Which managed identity are you using? Also Provide your function code.

But based on the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-configure-managed-identity) it tries to get a token from the following locations, in the said order, for access to your Azure resources:
A local cache shared between Microsoft applications
The current user context in Visual Studio
The current user context in Visual Studio Code
The current user context in the Azure CLI

Managed Identity doesn't work locally, you have to use DefaultAzureCredential instead.
